css is working in local, but not applied after running "npm run build" in build in react application
I am trying to override Muidrawer-paper CSS; it is applying in local after running "npm start", but is not applied when running the build package.
.css-12i7wg6-MuiPaper-root-MuiDrawer-paper {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 50px !important;
    outline: 0;
    left: 10px !important;
    max-width: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px !important;
    background: color-mix(in srgb, #D8D8D8, transparent 18%) !important;
}

My local application:

After running build package:

Why is my CSS not applying in the build package?
The CSS should be same in both locally and build package when running the react application.
Header.js
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import LayersIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Layers';
import  './Header.css';
//comment 
const drawerWidth = 240;

const openedMixin = (theme) => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
});

const closedMixin = (theme) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
  width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
  },
});

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
}));

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    ...(open && {
      ...openedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
    }),
    ...(!open && {
      ...closedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
    }),
  }),
);

export default function MiniDrawer() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = (index) => {
    console.log("index",index)
    setOpen(true);
   
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      
      <AppBar position="fixed" color="default" >
        <Toolbar variant="dense">
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open} 
     sx={{
      "& MuiPaper-root.css-12i7wg6-MuiPaper-root-MuiDrawer-paper": {
        position: "absolute !important",
        minHeight: "fit-content !important",
        top: "50px !important",
         outline: 0, left: "10px !important", width: "35px", padding:" 35px !important", background: "color-mix(in srgb, #D8D8D8, transparent 18%) !important"
      }
    }}
    //  style ={{position: "absolute !important",top: "50px !important", outline: 0, left: "10px !important", width: "35px", padding:" 35px !important", background: "color-mix(in srgb, #D8D8D8, transparent 18%) !important"}}
    >
       
        <List>
          {[
            "Home",
            "Layers",
           
          ].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
              <ListItemButton
                sx={{
                  minHeight: 48,
                  justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                  px: 2.5,
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                >
                  <Tooltip title="Home">
                 {index === 0 ? <HomeIcon />:null} 
                 </Tooltip>
                 <Tooltip title="Layers">
                 {index === 1 ? <LayersIcon />:null} 
                 </Tooltip>
          
              
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
       
      
      </Drawer>
     
    </Box>
  );
}

Header.css
.css-12i7wg6-MuiPaper-root-MuiDrawer-paper{
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 50px !important;
    outline: 0;
    left: 10px !important;
    max-width: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px !important;
    background:color-mix(in srgb, #D8D8D8, transparent 18%) !important;
}

App.js:
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Registration from './components/Registration';
import Header from './components/Header';


import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       
      <Header />
      
      <Paper className = 'footer'  sx={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0,backgroundColor:'rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.6)' }} elevation={3}>
        
      </Paper>

    </div>
      
    
  );
}

export default App;

App.css:

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}


I'm guessing this isn't a code problem. If you can, can you check these things & add them to the question: 1. if you check the build/ folder, do your CSS files show up there? Add a list of what files are showing up there. 2. If you open developer tools do App.css and Header.css show up in your sources/styles? Do you see anything different in the developer tools between local and build? (in console, in the sources, etc). 3. Can you show us the folder structure of your project, the contents of your package.json (all of them, if there's multiple) and any other configuration files?

When you build your React App for production, Material UI changes all class names and your code is minified. That is the reason your overridden CSS styles do not apply as no such class exists after a creating a production build.
The correct approach to applying customization in MUI involves creating a theme and applying it to the root component or adding inline classes. Though you could use either approach, I'll give an example of using inline classes as it'd be easier to grasp before delving completely into MUI customization.
To modify the style of the paper component inside the Drawer, you need to pass in the PaperProps prop to the drawer element. Here's an example of what you'd want to do:
A Part of your Header.js Code (Modified)


return (
  <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
    <AppBar position="fixed" color="default" >
      <Toolbar variant="dense">
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    <Drawer 
      variant="permanent" 
      open={open}
      PaperProps={{
         sx: {
            position: "absolute !important",
            top: "50px !important",
            outline: 0,
            left: "10px !important",
            maxWidth: "35px",
            paddingRight: "35px !important",
            background: "color-mix(in srgb, #D8D8D8, transparent 18 %) !important"
         }
      }}
    >
      <List>
        {[
          "Home",
          "Layers",
        ].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
            <ListItemButton
              sx={{
                minHeight: 48,
                justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                px: 2.5,
              }}
            >
              <ListItemIcon
                sx={{
                  minWidth: 0,
                  mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}
              >
                <Tooltip title="Home">
                  {index === 0 ? <HomeIcon /> : null}
                </Tooltip>
                <Tooltip title="Layers">
                  {index === 1 ? <LayersIcon /> : null}
                </Tooltip>
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Drawer>
  </Box>
);



